# Trend analysis and significance of multiple rasters with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have 30 rasters describing the average temperature of a region in Italy.
I would like a tool that calculates, at the pixel level (i.e. spatially explicit), both the slope of the trend (average annual increase) and the significance of the trend.

I have tried using GRASS r.series, but seems that it does not calculate the significance.

Comment: Have you considered using R for this?

Comment: @SPet I am trying to use R integrated in QGIS but I am not very familiar with it. 
Could you help me? Thank you

Comment: You can call QGIS from R, and write R scripts for QGIS. However, I think running the analysis with the GIS functions in R is the faster way to go. I am not familiar with trend analysis, but this may give you pointers. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325849/performing-trend-analysis-with-r. 
Learning R for GIS can be a steep learning curve, but worth it - even when familiar with GRASS or QGIS, as expands the possibilities of both.